# prevent GUI notification for Bluetooth Pairing

Tags: python, bluetooth, gui, raspbian-jessie

Currently, I am trying to control Bluetooth (pairing - connecting - removing ...) with my python code (by accessing to bluetoothctl through pexpect).

It actually works fine but I have a problem with bluetoothctl when I am trying to pair my Bluetooth speaker to raspberry pi. After pairing, a GUI dialog comes up and requests to accept the pairing

[image]

The pairing procedure does not finish until you accept this dialog. Is there any way to prevent GUI interaction during Bluetooth pairing?

Answer (score 1):

To stop getting the GUI notification, you need to stop the default BT process in raspberry pi. Right click on the BT icon on the task bar and you can see option to remove/stop it. You will no longer get GUI notifications. I haven't tried getting the GUI app back. But this worked for me when I tested my app I made using Qt and DBus.